# Wordpress Installation PHP Error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, rhel

THis is the update I get when I run the following command `php -v`

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/dbase.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/dbase.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/fileinfo.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/fileinfo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/json.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/json.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/mysql.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/mysqli.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/pdo.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/phar.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/phar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/zip.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/zip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm trying to install Wordpress on a RHEL Machine. I initially had gotten mySQL up and running and then realized that my PHP was version 5.1.6. I added another repo, installed PHP 5.3 and removed the old php packages.

The error I get on a browser when I open localhost/wp-admin/install.php is:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which
>   is required by WordPress.

I have the package `php-mysql.x86_64` installed and I can't figure out what the problem is.
I don't know what to do! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: look out for a version of php-curl.x86_64 for your new PHP version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured this out. The latest php version was installed. I was using 64 Bit RHEL and the libraries were in the `/usr/lib64` folder instead of the `/usr/lib` folder. Once I changed that bit in the `php.ini` file, it ran like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Install required *PHP* libraries. RHEL installation command ( with all required modules for Wordpress):

```
sudo yum install php-bcmath  php-cli  php-common  php-devel  php-gd  php-imap  php-mbstring  php-mcrypt  php-mysqlnd  php-odbc  php-pdo  php-pear php-pecl-geoip  php-pecl-jsonc  php-pecl-jsonc-devel  php-pecl-zip  php-pgsql  php-process  php-tidy  php-xml  php-xmlrpc
```

Install EPEL repos to update to latest PHP:

```
#CentOS 6 64Bit
sudo wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum update php
```

EPEL repos installation process for other versions - [How to Enable EPEL Repository for RHEL/CentOS 7.x/6.x/5.x](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/)

#### EDIT 1:

In order to disable other repositories, see and edit `.repo` files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory and set `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`. After all don't forget to run:

```
yum clean all
```

Comment: The EPEL repo is already added. I get this when I hit `sudo yum update php`:
`Skipping security plugin, no data`
`Setting up Update Process`
`No Packages marked for Update`
But what bothers me is that my company has its own repo and when I want hit the first command you gave, it shows me packages with versions 5.1.x instead of the 5.3 I need. How do I ask yum to pull only from a single repo?

Comment: @Sammy You should edit files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` and switch `enable = 1` to `0` to other repos. After all, I forgot to mention, that you should run `yum clean all` and then run *PHP* update again.